# Trying to assign a number value to a non-numerical value in Excel but still display the non-numerical value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a timesheet and I need the cells to show the text like "Morning, Evening, Night" etc but the cell needs to have a numerical value but still show the text, not the value.  The numerical value then gets pulled onto another sheet by the date which I I did this with

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D4,Schedule!A72:B126,2,FALSE),"")
```

Here is the first sheet that needs to display the text not the numerical value:
[image: Here is the first sheet that needs to display the text not the numerical value:]

This is the second sheet that the numerical value gets pulled to using the VLOOKUP by the date:
[image: this is the second sheet that the numerical value gets pulled to using the VLOOKUP by the date:]

Is this possible?  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One possible building block to achieve your goal:

Type this into four consecutive cells:

```
1  
0   
-1  
Blaha
```

- Select those cells,
- chose `Format cells` from menu or Ribbon   *(Shortcut: CTRL+1)*.
- Select`Custom` or `User defined` (Excel or LibreOfice)
- Type `"Positive";"Negative";"Zero";"TEXT"` in the field used to define the format
- Click `OK`

Now play with it, edit the cells, change values...
Prefix a value with `'` to get it to be text.